# NSolve unable to solve system of equations with domain specification

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, regions

I have a system of two equations in two unknowns that I would like to solve with NSolve *within a specified region*.

However, while Mathematica solves the system if I omit the domain specification, it fails to do so when I include it.

Here is an example:

```
eq1 = (-0.9781476007338057` + Cos[x] Cos[y])^2 + 
    Cos[y]^2 Sin[x]^2 + (-0.20791169081775931` + Sin[y])^2 == 
    0.04370479853238872`;

eq2 = -0.058944236842231254` (-0.9781476007338057` + Cos[x] Cos[y]) - 
    0.20040259242104053` Cos[y] Sin[x] - 
    0.008317236704697833` (-0.20791169081775931` + Sin[y]) == 0;
```

`NSolve` returns four solutions:

```
NSolve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]

{{x -> -3.13939, y -> 3.14158}, {x -> -3.12983, 
  y -> 2.72301}, {x -> 0.0022017, y -> 0.0000114031}, {x -> 0.0117594,
   y -> 0.418582}}
```

Among these four solutions, I am only interested in the one that has positive $x$ and is sufficiently different from $(0,0)$, i.e., the last one. Hence I try to solve

```
NSolve[{eq1, eq2, x \[Element] Interval[{0.01, 0.5}]}, {x, y}]
```

which Mathematica returns unevaluated.

Can anybody help?

Comment: `FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {{x, .5}, {y, .5}}]`

Comment: First, there is more than one solution that has positive $x$ and is sufficiently different from $(0,0)$. Second, the equation is transcendental, not [algebraic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicEquation.html), although perhaps you didn't mean algebraic in its mathematical sense but meant "symbolic." Perhaps this: `Solve[Rationalize[Rationalize@{eq1, eq2, 0.01 < x}, 0], {x, y}, Method -> Reduce] /. s_?NumericQ /; ! IntegerQ[s] && FreeQ[s, Pi] :> N@s` or with the condition `0.01 < x || x > 0 && Abs[y] > 0.01`

Comment: @MichaelE2: In view of the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ it's enough to consider the solutions on $(-\pi,\pi]\times(-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Can you elaborate and ground " Your suggestion leaves the problem unfinished"? TIA.

Comment: `NSolve[{eq1, eq2, x > -Pi, x <= Pi, y > -Pi, y <= Pi}, {x, y}]` results in `{{x -> -3.13939, y -> 3.14158}, {x -> -3.12983, 
  y -> 2.72301}, {x -> 0.0022017, y -> 0.0000114031}, {x -> 0.0117594,
   y -> 0.418582}}` the same as `NSolve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes, of course, The solution `{{x -> -3.13939, y -> 3.14158}` generates the series of the solutions `{{x -> -3.13939+2*Pi*k, y -> 3.14158+2*Pi*n}` , where `{n.k}\[Element] Integers`. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user64494 I'm glad to see you admit that work is needed to transform the solutions over the fundamental domain to a full solution set. Further, the set needs to be truncated to those that satisfy the constraints -- that is, more work is needed. Clearly you have proved it is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting `y` too, we succeed:

```
NSolve[{eq1, eq2, x >= 0.01, x <= 0.5, y >= -5, y <= 5}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

or

```
NSolve[{eq1, eq2, x \[Element] Interval[{0.01, 0.5}], y >= -5, y <= 5}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> 0.0117594, y -> 0.418582}}`

Comment: I am on Win7, Mma12.2 and it repeats the input back with both these variations. Is there some other option I have to use or is this new functionality? The functionality shown by OP works however.

Comment: It's strange. [The documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) says (at the bottom) `NSolve` was updated latest time in 2014 ( version 10.0). Works for me in 12.3.1 on Windows 10. Try it in cloud.

Comment: @Syed - They also are unevaluated with v12.2 on a Mac

Answer (score 1):

Combining the `FindRoot` usage suggested by @DerekH with manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
 sol = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {{x, xcoord}, {y, ycoord}}];
 Show[{ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eq1, eq2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[sol, Red, Bold], GridLines -> Automatic],
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, y} /. sol]}]
   }],
 {{xcoord, 0}, 0, 10, 0.2},
 {{ycoord, 0}, 0, 10, 0.2}
 ]
```

[image]

If the OP wants to choose something sufficiently removed from the origin, there seem to be a lot of choices.

**EDIT**
A more satisfying result would however be all the solutions in a bounded region.

```
solreduce = 
 Reduce[{x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 5] && eq1 && eq2, {x, y}]
sol3 = {ToRules@solreduce}
```

gives the ten closest results around origin bounded by the disk used to demarcate the region.

Comment: The periodicity of `Sin` and `Cos` implies the periodicity of the solutions. It's enough to consider `{x,-Pi,Pi}` and `{y,-Pi,Pi}`.

Comment: Agreed and the output of the `Reduce` shows that too. I have included this to show usage.